# SSL сертификаты

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер, apache2

Уважаемые господа!

Заменяю на веб-серверах (apache, nginx) старый SSL сертификат на новый. Рестартую демонов.В браузере по прежнему светится старый. Может где кэш SSL на сервере хранится. В браузере очищал.

Куда смотреть?

Comment: Мож не то меняете. Попробуйте без сертификата, удалите его, и поймете.

Comment: То. Без сертификата демоны не стартуют.

Comment: Да, глупость сказал. Просто в нормальной - дефолтной конфе у апача точно нет кэша.

Comment: ок, а попробуйте дефолтные пропишите, которые в /etc/ssl/ что то там...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в моей неосведомленности о наличии реверсивного прокси на nginx в сети (недавно работаю), так что заменил сертификат на нем и все заработало.